# Why is my code failing when I'm iterating through files in a folder on my computer?

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I am trying to traverse all files (and files in subfolders) within a folder. However, the code I am currently using is producing the error:

> Failed to set posix_spawn_file_actions for fd -1 at index 0 with errno 9

Why is the following code causing this error after a couple hundred files have been traversed?

```
func iterationForAll() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    guard let path = filePath else {return}
    guard let enumerator: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: path) else {return}
    while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as ? String {
        print(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? If so, you need to set the corrrct entitlement to read the file system.

Comment: @Alexander I don't think it is. I am still able to traverse through a few hundred files. It just fails after a certain amount. Could this be caused if it is sandboxed? If so, how can I set the correct entitlement to read the file system?

Comment: Where does a guy named 'filePath' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato filePath is a locally stored variable. In this case filePath = “desktop/quiz_app”

Comment: "I am still able to traverse through a few hundred files. It just fails after a certain amount." You should have mentioned this in your question :)

Comment: Might be caused by the sandboxing file memory bug: https://buckleyisms.com/blog/anecdotes-about-the-macos-sandbox-file-limit/

Comment: @helloworld12345 try using `autoreleasepool { }` inside your while loop

Comment: @Willeke I am using BigSur

Comment: You say "a couple hundred files". Could you be more specific? Is the limit, perhaps, 256 files? If so that's a known limit.

Comment: @matt specifically, it is ~851 files, but the file it fails on is different every time so it may be 849 sometimes or 853.

Comment: It's still interesting that it's a pretty fixed limit. This suggests that you really are hitting some built-in fixed limit. Do you claim I can reproduce the issue just by running the script you provided?

Comment: @matt I assume so, just set filePath equal to the path to an xcode project folder with a similar number of files and run it. As long as the app isn’t sandboxed it should be reproducible!

Comment: Do you do anything else with `element` besides `print(element)`? Have you tried using URLs and `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)` instead of paths?